# Temperature of a categorical distribution with given logits and entropy

Tags: probability-distributions, closed-form, entropy

Let's consider a probability mass function $p(x)$ over integers $1\leq x\leq n$ and its entropy $h$, parameterized by the *logits* $l\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and the *inverse temperature* $\beta\in\mathbb{R}_+,\beta>0$,
$$
p(x)=\frac{e^{\beta l_x}}{\sum_{y=1}^n e^{\beta l_y}},
\qquad
h=\sum_{x=1}^n p(x)\ln p(x).
$$
Given the logits $l$ and the entropy $h$, is it possible to solve for $\beta$ in closed form? If not, why?

Comment: $p(x)$ is independent of $\beta$.

Comment: That was a stupid typo -- $\beta$ should be in the exponent.